# Remove apostrophes from filename before the Handler file upload it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

Due to some issues with my hosting server supporting apostrophes, I need to remove them from the file o files before they are uploaded.

I'm using the JQuery Upload File script, and this is the link to the UploadHandler script file I need to modify, but I need a little help doing it so. Can someone please tell me what I need to change in this script in order to remove those apostrophes before they are processed?

**UploadHandler.php**

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php

Please Help.

Comment: please post your code here thank you

Comment: I tried, but it has more that 50000 characters and Stackoverflow won't allow more than 30000. That's why i'm using a link @suspectus

Comment: boil the code size down to just sufficient to illustrate your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to add to the function **trim_file_name()**.

Add this to a new line after line #455

```
$name = str_replace("'", "", $name);
```